# Why is my STM32 program not starting at the first line?

Tags: c, gdb, stm32

I am using arm-none-eabi-gdb, and I am working on STM32F2xx. It should start following the first line, however I find it skips some lines.

#### Code:

```
uint32_t SystemCoreClock = 12000000;
__I uint8_t AHBPrescTable[16] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9};

void SystemInit(void)
{
    /* Reset the RCC clock configuration to the default reset state ------------ */
    /* Set HSION bit */
    RCC->CR |= (uint32_t)0x00000001;

    /* Reset CFGR register */
    RCC->CFGR = 0x00000000;

    /* Reset HSEON, CSSON and PLLON bits */
    RCC->CR &= (uint32_t)0xFEF6FFFF;

    /* Reset PLLCFGR register */
    RCC->PLLCFGR = 0x24003010;

    /* Reset HSEBYP bit */
    RCC->CR &= (uint32_t)0xFFFBFFFF;
```

And in my gdb debug it starts as the following:

```
(gdb) tar ext:4242
Remote debugging using :4242
0x08000354 in SystemInit () at system_stm32f2xx.c:154
154      RCC->CR &= (uint32_t)0xFFFBFFFF;
(gdb)
```

Which is not starting at uint32_t SystemCoreClock = 12000000;?

Edited here:
And my follow question is , even the variable is ignore during the run ,
why it is not starting @ RCC->CR |= (uint32_t)0x00000001;?
thanks

And my CFLAGS as

```
CFLAGS += -fno-common -Wall -O0 -g -mcpu=cortex-m3 -mthumb
CFLAGS += -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections
```

Comment: As "s.p.d." explained no code is required to initialize global variables, so debugger can not stop on that. You also did not show how you loaded your code and how you started it. This looks like you attached to already running system, which if it was not stalled, would not wait at first statement.

Comment: @dbrank0. I loaded the code by using this command
arm-none-eabi-gdb main.elf 
and i started by using this command 
 tar ext:4242 using texane/stlink.
following my reply to ＠S.p.d  i wonder why it wont start @　RCC->CR |= (uint32_t)0x00000001;。

Answer (score 3):

Execution of bare-metal embedded programs start at the address pointed to by the reset vector or perhaps at a fixed reset address, which is platform-dependent.

On the Cortex-M series, the reset vector is at address 4, i.e. the second 4-byte word in the flash (or RAM, depending on the boot pins). Reading this location gives you the reset address, which points to the very first function that's executed after reset. This function is usually called `Reset_Handler`, and it's responsible for initializing global variables, calling whatever needs to be called before `main()` (including `SystemInit()`), and finally transferring control to `main()`. The assembly source code is usually in a file named `startup_stm32f2xx.s` or similar, depending on your toolchain.

You can set a breakpoint on `Reset_Handler`, and see how the global variables are initialized. You won't see the corresponding variable definitions though; it's just a fixed table copied from flash to RAM (data section, variables with initial values other than 0), and filling the rest with 0 (BSS section). To find out which variable belongs to which memory address, you can consult the `.map` file generated by the linker.

Comment: @ Peter Mortebsen. I have try to add breakpoint to the Reset_Handler.
However once i start the program by  tar ext:4242 it still skip to 
(gdb) b Reset_Handler
Breakpoint 1 at 0x8001ebc: file startup_stm32f205xx.s, line 79.
(gdb) tar ext:4242
Remote debugging using :4242
0x08000354 in SystemInit () at system_stm32f2xx.c:154
154   RCC->CR &= (uint32_t)0xFFFBFFFF;
 anything else i could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The global data is initialized *before* the `main` function starts running. And global variables that are initialized at definition (like the ones you show) are actually initialized *by the compiler* and not at all at run-time.

Comment: thanks for your comment, i know little about .bss and .data and will explore on it, 
so even if skip the variable , why it skips 4 line until to
154   RCC->CR &= (uint32_t)0xFFFBFFFF; ?

And how can i cross check whether the HSION is set or not?
thanks

Comment: @ApexYu I don't know that much about remote debugging using GDB, but it seems to me that all it does is stop the remote execution where it happens to be.

Comment: On embedded platforms, global variables are indeed initalized runtime.

Comment: @berendi It really depends. In my years I have never come across a platform where the data section is not just copied into RAM by the loader.